# List of surrounding towns within a given radius

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get a list of surrounding "towns" within a given radius? Can someone please give me some pointers for this if it can be done? Thanks!

Comment: You could create a hack, within the circular boundary, add a bunch of markers (density depending on radius), and reverse geocode each of these markers. results[1].formatted_address should contain the town/city name (I'm testing in the USA). Keep a list of these towns without duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Maps doesn't allow this.

However, you can use geonames.org, but even they don't have a list of nearby towns. The way to do it appears to be

1. get a list of nearby postcodes
2. look up the placename for each postcode
3. remove the duplicates

[Find Nearby Postal codes](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearbyPostalCodes)

[Postal code search](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#postalCodeSearch)

Answer (score 5):

This is not a map question.
A suitable solution is using php/Mysql

If you get the the data for the required country from [geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/)
and use this to create table.
Then use the [‘haversine’](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) formula to select towns in the required radius.
If you are using Google maps this [demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)  can help